# Can't select text in input box on IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, input, dojo, dojo-dnd

I have an input box that is inside of a div, the div has a background image and the input box inside of it is positioned and limited in size / font to work nicely with the background image.  In FF everything works as expected, in IE though there is a major issue.  I can't select the text inside of the input box using the mouse or use short-cuts like shift-end/home, ctrl-left/right.  You can move around using the mouse keys and use the delete/backspace keys to adjust the text.  The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class='my_container'>
  <input type='text' name='my_text_input' class='my_input' />
</div>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I would like to add some more information, i'm attaching a Dojo dnd Target to the outside div.  If I don't attach the dnd then I can do the selection, once i've attached the dnd, i can't select the text anymore.

Comment: Hmm, I have a lot of code that boils done to your example that works fine for me. Are you sure you can reproduce the problem with the snippet you gave us?

Comment: Are you sure that the div is not behind something else? (Although that wouldn't explain not being able to select with hotkeys)

Comment: Correct.  Here are the specific styling details.  The outside main container has a large background image that part of it is designated for an input box.  The input box, is transparent and absolutely positioned inside of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is rather straight forward once one digs through the code being executed by dojo!!!

In the object being passed to the dojo.dnd.Target constructor, one needs to set the skipForm attribute to true.

so, it looks something like this:

```
var dndTarget = new dojo.dnd.Target(searchBox, {
  isSource: false,
  copyOnly: true,
  selfCopy: false,
  selfAccept: false,
  skipForm: true  // <-- THIS IS THE FIX
});
```

This seems to tell dojo not to connect to the input elements and thus works as expected in IE.

Comment: It would help greatly if you mentioned that the input in question was in a draggable element to begin with. Otherwise it was not clear how it is related to Dojo. DnD is thoroughly documented: http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/dnd, including skipForm --- no need to dig in the code for that.

Comment: My appologies, its not a draggable though, its only a dropable area.  I know they are the same ;)  I did dig through the documentation, I was using the api doc, which was very unclear on this term.  Do you think you can update the API doc so that it is more closely connected to what is there on the dojocampus site?